# Recovering css class name

Tags: c#

How can I recover a Css class that was add via JQuery in my `<asp:TextBox>` component ?

Example:

**ASPX**

`<asp:TextBox ID='txtTest' runat='server' CssClass='inputText'></asp:TextBox>`

**JQUERY**

`$('#txtTest').addClass('testClass');`

**Page Renderized**

`<input type='text' ID='txtTest' CssClass='inputText testClass' />`

**Code Behind**

How can I recover the `testClass` that was add via Jquery in my `<asp:TextBox>` component ?

I tryied `this.txtTest.CssClass` but return just `inputText` class.

Comment: You can't since the class attribute was modified in the browser. Asp.net do not track this kind of changes...

Comment: @devundef I can recover via javascript but I tought that I could recover through code behind also.

Comment: that information isn't accessible from the codebehind if its modified by the client.

Comment: No, this kind of changes in the DOM are not sent to server. If you really need this information on the server side you can add a hidden field and store the class name in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve this because changes to style aren't even submitted in the request. ASP.NET will reconstruct the object from what "it knows" about it, that is, the original markup in this case.

If you must keep track of this, then you are going to have to add the new class to a hidden element and retrieve it on code-behind:

```
<input type="hidden" id="addedClasses" name="addedClasses" />
```

Then the jQuery part:

```
$('#txtTest').addClass('testClass');
$('#addedClasses').val('testClass');
```

And on code behind:

```
string addedClasses = Request.Params["addedClasses"];
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think to do this is to put the TextBox's class into a `Hidden` field with javascript  and have it be sent back to the server on a POST.

Comment: it can't be on the class for the hidden, but the value.

Comment: @DanielA.White, that's what I meant, I edited to make that a little clearer.